# Where is Dyalog installed on Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, directory, windows-installer, dyalog

Some documents refer to things in the Dyalog installation directory. How can I easily find out where that directory is?

I searched the internet and found the SETUP README for version 18.2, which shows the non-Administrator install directory, but I installed Dyalog with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask the interpreter where it is located, which will be the installation directory unless you've moved it yourself:

From the interactive APL session, enter `]config DYALOG`

If you want to get this value under program control, use `⎕SE.Dyalog.Utils.Config'DYALOG'`

If the above fail, then your session object hasn't been populated. In that case, use `⊢2⎕NQ#'GetEnvironment' 'DYALOG'`

By the way, this works cross-platform. On Windows only, if you've moved the interpreter, but want to know where it was originally installed, use `DYALOGINSTALLDIR` instead of `DYALOG` in the above.